# How to retrieve all linked rows and columns without using JOIN in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables linked (one-to-many, table1 -> table2).

DB.Schema1.Table1 - the primary key here is "thekey" --parent
DB.Schema1.Table2 - referencing field is "thekey" --child

Is there an easy way to retrieve all linked rows/columns **without using the JOIN statement**?

I thought this might work, but obviously it doesn't:

```
select * from Schema1.table1, Schema1.table2 where thekey = 'key1'
```

Here is the code to re-create the schemas and tables if needed:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Schema1];
CREATE SCHEMA [Schema2];

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE [Schema1].[table1] ( 
    [thekey] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL, 
    [col1] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL, 
    [col2] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL, 
    [col3] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( [thekey] ) )
GO;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE [Schema1].[table2] ( 
    [thekey] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL, 
    [colx] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL, 
    [coly] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL, 
    [colz] VARCHAR( 256 ) NOT NULL )
GO;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[table2]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [lnk_table1_table2]
    FOREIGN KEY ([thekey])
    REFERENCES [Schema1].[table1]( [thekey] )
    ON DELETE No Action
    ON UPDATE No Action
GO;

ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[table2] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [lnk_table1_table2]
GO;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Schema1.table1 ( [col1], [col2], [col3], [thekey]) 
VALUES ( 'value of table 1 col1', 'value of table 1 col2', 'value of table 1 col3', 'key1' );
INSERT INTO Schema1.table2 ( [colx], [coly], [colz], [thekey]) 
VALUES ( 'value of row 1 colx in table2', 'value of row 1 coly in table2', 'value of row 1 colz in table2', 'key1' );
INSERT INTO Schema1.table2 ( [colx], [coly], [colz], [thekey]) 
VALUES ( 'value of row 2 colx in table2', 'value of row 2 coly in table2', 'value of row 2 colz in table2', 'key1' );
INSERT INTO Schema1.table2 ( [colx], [coly], [colz], [thekey]) 
VALUES ( 'value of row 3 colx in table2', 'value of row 3 coly in table2', 'value of row 3 colz in table2', 'key2' );
```

Comment: Nope. If SQL Server supported `NATURAL JOIN`, you could at least write `FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2 WHERE table1.thekey = 'key1'`, but it does not. You must write out all `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: What is the reason for requirement?

Comment: Join can be realised in "where" clause in implicit way, just write condition between keys. But this is relational join (but hidden)

Comment: WEI_DBA: The reason for the requirement is that I would like to join many linked tables and would not like to use multiple join statements. By using JOIN statements does the performance suffer? can the JOIN statements take advantage of indexes?.

Comment: If you want the information from both table, you use `JOIN`.  That's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always preferred to use Joins. I am not sure what is the reason behind not using the Joins but you can do something like this:

```
select * 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.thekey = t2.thekey
```

Comment: Which is almost the same thing without join keyword. I can't make sense of this requirement either.

Comment: Thsi is pretty much `JOIN`.  The only difference is it does not have the work JOIN.

Comment: I selected this as the answer but for future reference, I agree with all comments above regarding the need to use JOIN statements rather than using this solution.